# Ruby On Rails: CanCan with Devise error 'undefined method `find_by_name' for #<Role:0x304ad18>

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm very confused of cancan, I tried to get roles for cancan out of my mysql database. I'm using a controller which got no actions like show/edit/destroy (it's called a Non RESTful Controller I think?).
I got a Role_id column in my user table and id and rolename in my roles table.

All I get is this error:

undefined method `find_by_name' for #

```
Ability.rb:
 class Ability
      include CanCan::Ability
      def initialize(user)
        can :manage, :all if user.role? :admin
    end
    end
```

And here is my User.rb:

```
User.rb:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :firstname, :lastname, :birthday
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  belongs_to :role

def role?(role)
    return !!self.role.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end
end
```

Role.rb:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  attr_accessible :users, :name 
end
```

And here the controller I'm working in:

```
class WsdlController < ApplicationController
 authorize_resource :class => false
    $liga_id = 456
    $liga_short = "bl1"
    $saison = 2012

    def connect
        @client = Savon::Client.new("http://www.openligadb.de/Webservices/Sportsdata.asmx?WSDL")
        @output = ""
    end

    def get_all_for_new_saison
        if @client.nil?
            connect
        end
        #get_teams_by_league_saison
        #get_matchdata_by_league_saison
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_by_name` is an `ActiveRecord` **class method**.  (See the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) Guide)  You are invoking it like an **instance method**.

Try changing this:

```
def role?(role)
    return !!self.role.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end
```

to something like this:

```
def role?(role_name)
    return self.role.present? && self.role.name == role_name.to_s
end
```

Of course, in ruby, both `return` and `self` are optional.